# Filter a row using a column from another data table

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

> I have a (Household) table which have two columns: firstname and lastname. The second table (Complaints) also has two columns: respondents and remarks. Now im trying to check when the selected row in (household) has the same name values to the respondents column and has "UNSETTLED" value in remarks column. Then it will show household has records. If the value of respondents has a match but the remarks is = SETTLED then then the household has no records.

[This is where to select the household](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCY9F.png)

> and when i select a row and click the button use selected

[This form will open and the household has/no records, will show up in the black panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIzpE.png)

> I dont know what im doing wrong here so here's my code

```
    Dim i As Integer
    i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index


    Dim householdid = DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value


    Dim GLOBALid = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value


    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        con.Open()
    End If



    Try


        Dim command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Household WHERE ID=@id", con)
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(command)


        With command
            .Parameters.Add("@id", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = GLOBALid


        End With

        command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand("SELECT count(*)  FROM Complaint WHERE respondents LIKE '% @lastname %' OR respondents LIKE '% @firstname %' AND remarks=UNSETTLED ", con)
        Dim da1 As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd1)
        With cmd1
            .Parameters.Add("@lastname", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value
            .Parameters.Add("@firstname", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value

        End With



        'Dim numrows As Integer = 0
        'numrows = cmd.ExecuteScalar()


        Dim rowcount = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar())


        If rowcount >= 1 Then

            BrgyclearanceWithRecords.Label17.ForeColor = Color.Red
            BrgyclearanceWithRecords.Label17.Text = "Resident's Name has a match with an Existing unsettled complain!"

        ElseIf rowcount = 0 Then
            'BrgyclearanceWithRecords.Panel1.Visible = True

            BrgyclearanceWithRecords.Label17.ForeColor = Color.Green
            BrgyclearanceWithRecords.Label17.Text = "Resident's Name has no match with an Existing unsettled complain!"

        End If




        con.Close()



    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try



    BrgyclearanceWithRecords.Show()
    BrgyclearanceWithRecords.BringToFront()


End Sub
```

Comment: Complaints table has names combined into one field? Should not be saving names into Complaints but just ID instead. If `respondents` field is a lookup in table, then its value is ID, not names, and your LIKE criteria will fail. Is the table name Complaint or Complaints? You use an `s` in narrative but it is missing in the code.

Comment: Value of respondents is not ID but its the combination of firstname and lastname. Will the LIKE criteria wont work?

Comment: Im having a problem understanding how i can have the result of the resident have/dont have unsettled complain.

Answer (score 0):

I don't guarantee it solves every problem but..

```
WHERE respondents LIKE '% @lastname %'
```

it doesn't work like this; that will literally just search for any rows where the respondents field contains the text `" @lastname "`

```
WHERE respondents LIKE @lastname
```

and if you want to put wildcards you put them in the value

```
Parameters.Add("@lastname", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "Smith%"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think your database should look something like this.

[image]

Where the `ID` in the `Households` table is the Primary Key and has a one to many relationship to the `HouseholdID` Foreign Key in the `Complaints` table.

I am guessing that `DataGridView1` contains the `Households` and the first column contains the `ID` column.

The `Using` block includes the connection and the command. Both need to be disposed. `End Using` also closes the connection.

When you are using a literal string in the `Where` criteria, it needs to be surrounded by single quotes.

Since you are only retrieving a single value from the database you can use `ExecuteScalar()` which returns an `Object`, thus the `CInt()`.

Once the connection is safetly closed and disposed with the `End Using`, you can check your returned value, `count`, and take the required actions.

```
Private OPConStr As String = "Your connection string."

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
    Dim householdid = CInt(DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value)
    Try
        Using con As New OleDbConnection(OPConStr),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT count(*)  FROM Complaints WHERE HouseholdID = @ID AND Remarks = 'UNSETTLED';", con)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = householdid
            con.Open()
            count = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    If count >= 1 Then
        BrgyclearanceWithRecords.Label17.ForeColor = Color.Red
        BrgyclearanceWithRecords.Label17.Text = "Resident's Name has a match with an Existing unsettled complain!"
    Else
        BrgyclearanceWithRecords.Label17.ForeColor = Color.Green
        BrgyclearanceWithRecords.Label17.Text = "Resident's Name has no match with an Existing unsettled complain!"
    End If
    BrgyclearanceWithRecords.Show()
    BrgyclearanceWithRecords.BringToFront()
End Sub
```

Comment: My complaints table only has ID, fullname, Remarks. Compared to the household's firstname and lastname column combined, Is it possible for the fullname column to act like a foreign key? if the fullname has the same values to the firstname and lastname how should i use that count int boolean to differentiate the records?

Comment: That would be poor database design. Primary Key / Foreign Key fields shouldn't have any real meaning except to uniquely identify the record. Names change, women get married and get a new name.

Comment: But i use the household datatable to add values to the fullname in complaints so it shouldn't be a problem right? it is only used to check if the name has an unsettled complaints.

Comment: I am not an expert on the subject but a poor design at the beginning can lead to problems down the road. Try it and see. I may work out just fine for you.

Comment: Yes I understand that, its only for a school project. Please can you help me have an idea how to make use of the int boolean and a query with WHERE [column] Like

Comment: If you don't want to use ID as criteria, then don't include it in combobox RowSource. Using name to filter/search is poor design. There could be multiple households with same last name.

Comment: @June7 If you comment is addressing the Reniel then please precede it with @ and the his name. If you are addressing me, which is how it seems, then I don't understand the comment as a comment on my answer.